# XmlSerializer null reference exception appears in .NET 4.0 but not in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm having a strange exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterRules.XSArrayInfo.get_Item(Object a, Int32 i)
>   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterRules.Write5_SearchAndReturnRules(String n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
>   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterRules.Write6_SearchAndReturnRules(Object o)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
>   at MergeExcelFilesForm.SaveSearchRulesToFile(StreamWriter stream)

```
 using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName))
 {
       SaveSearchRulesToFile(streamWriter);
 }

 public void SaveSearchRulesToFile(StreamWriter stream)
 {
       var rules = GetRules();
       var rulesSerializer = new XmlSerializer(rules.GetType());
       rulesSerializer.Serialize(stream, rules);
 }
```

Serialized class is quite simple, has no special attributes (giving just main class, don't think child classes are important, because they are even simplier):

```
 public class Rules
 {
    public List<SearchRule> SearchRules { get; set; }
    public List<CopyRule> CopyRules { get; set; }
    public int SourceHeaderRow { get; set; }
    public int DestinationHeaderRow { get; set; }
 } 


public class SearchRule
{
    public HeaderItem SearchFor { get; set; }
    public HeaderItem SearchIn { get; set; }

    public SearchRule()
    {            
    }

    public SearchRule(int indexFor, int indexIn)
    {
        SearchFor = new HeaderItem(indexFor);
        SearchIn = new HeaderItem(indexIn);
    }
}

public class HeaderItem
{
    public HeaderItem()
    {            
    }

    public HeaderItem(int columnIndex, string displayName)
    {
        ColumnIndex = columnIndex;
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }

    public HeaderItem(int columnIndex) : this(columnIndex, columnIndex.ToString())
    {            
    }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return DisplayName;
    }
}
```

Now the interesting part - it runs fine when .NET 4.5 is installed and fails if it is only .NET 4.0 is on target machine, target platform is .NET 4.0.

Comment: It would return null despite what .net framework is installed, but no, exception comes from generated assembly instead of GetType().

Comment: I suspect the class involved is part of understanding the issue: pity we can't see that. I suspect te only way to debug it woud be to use sgen.exe and reflector/ildasm to inspect the generated assembly, but ultimately it sounds like a framework bug, now fixed. Hence understanding the type may help suggest a workaround

Comment: @MarcGravell I've added child classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can debug XML serializing processes with:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
        <add name="XmlSerialization.Compilation" value="1" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

The generated source classes are in your local temp folder. So you can easily step through the parsing stuff and maybe detect the problem in your XML file.

Comment: looking at the code generated by 4.0 and 4.5 frameworks, I have to say they are quite different and so far it looks like problem lies in fact, that generated assembly is tightly coupled to a dll where type is, as long as we're using dll packing it may be the issue with 4.0 generated code.